# Launch box spout

Tags: php, excel

I downloaded Box / Spout here https://github.com/box/spout but I have a problem to launch Spout.
I copied the file to the folder of WAMP.

```
<?php 
use Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->openToBrowser($fileName); // stream data directly to the browser
$writer->addRows($multipleRows); // add multiple rows at a time
$writer->close();
?>
```

I created the file index.php and Spout files are in the folder WWW/Spout/Box/Common, Reader and Writer. 
And I have this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\Spout\Index.php on line 5

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Did you include Writefacory file corectly, I mean the location of writefactory file??

Comment: Thk you for you answer:P, my WriteFactory.php file is in www\Spout\Box\Spout\Writer ... I don't understand ...

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the files is not enough. If you don't use Composer (which is the recommended way to use Spout), you need to add an additional autoloader (that will autoload the classes for you). Since Spout is PSR4 compliant, autoloading its classes is not really hard.

Here is some working code that you can use to autoload Spout classes:

**Psr4Autoloader.php**

```
<?php

namespace Autoloader;

class Psr4Autoloader
{
    /**
     * An associative array where the key is a namespace prefix and the value
     * is an array of base directories for classes in that namespace.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $prefixes = array();

    /**
     * Register loader with SPL autoloader stack.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Adds a base directory for a namespace prefix.
     *
     * @param string $prefix The namespace prefix.
     * @param string $base_dir A base directory for class files in the
     * namespace.
     * @param bool $prepend If true, prepend the base directory to the stack
     * instead of appending it; this causes it to be searched first rather
     * than last.
     * @return void
     */
    public function addNamespace($prefix, $base_dir, $prepend = false)
    {
        // normalize namespace prefix
        $prefix = trim($prefix, '\\') . '\\';

        // normalize the base directory with a trailing separator
        $base_dir = rtrim($base_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '/';

        // initialize the namespace prefix array
        if (isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false) {
            $this->prefixes[$prefix] = array();
        }

        // retain the base directory for the namespace prefix
        if ($prepend) {
            array_unshift($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
        } else {
            array_push($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads the class file for a given class name.
     *
     * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
     * @return mixed The mapped file name on success, or boolean false on
     * failure.
     */
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        // the current namespace prefix
        $prefix = $class;

        // work backwards through the namespace names of the fully-qualified
        // class name to find a mapped file name
        while (false !== $pos = strrpos($prefix, '\\')) {

            // retain the trailing namespace separator in the prefix
            $prefix = substr($class, 0, $pos + 1);

            // the rest is the relative class name
            $relative_class = substr($class, $pos + 1);

            // try to load a mapped file for the prefix and relative class
            $mapped_file = $this->loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class);
            if ($mapped_file) {
                return $mapped_file;
            }

            // remove the trailing namespace separator for the next iteration
            // of strrpos()
            $prefix = rtrim($prefix, '\\');   
        }

        // never found a mapped file
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Load the mapped file for a namespace prefix and relative class.
     * 
     * @param string $prefix The namespace prefix.
     * @param string $relative_class The relative class name.
     * @return mixed Boolean false if no mapped file can be loaded, or the
     * name of the mapped file that was loaded.
     */
    protected function loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class)
    {
        // are there any base directories for this namespace prefix?
        if (isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        // look through base directories for this namespace prefix
        foreach ($this->prefixes[$prefix] as $base_dir) {

            // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory,
            // replace namespace separators with directory separators
            // in the relative class name, append with .php
            $file = $base_dir
                  . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class)
                  . '.php';

            // if the mapped file exists, require it
            if ($this->requireFile($file)) {
                // yes, we're done
                return $file;
            }
        }

        // never found it
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * If a file exists, require it from the file system.
     * 
     * @param string $file The file to require.
     * @return bool True if the file exists, false if not.
     */
    protected function requireFile($file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**autoload.php**

```
<?php

require_once "Psr4Autoloader.php";

$loader = new \Autoloader\Psr4Autoloader;
$loader->register();
$loader->addNamespace('Box\Spout', 'vendor/box/spout/src/Spout');
```

Once you have added these 2 files to your project, make sure that the *require_once* path is correct in autoload.php and finally add *require_once "path/to/autoload.php"* in your root file (like *index.php*) or wherever you think it's more appropriate.