# Failed opening 'spout-2.4.3\spout-2.4.3\src\Spout\Autoloader\autoload.php'

Tags: php, spout

> PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'spout-2.4.3\spout-2.4.3\src\Spout\Autoloader\autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear')

I uploaded my site online and I am getting that error. I am uploading a xlsx file. It works fine in local, but gets this error online.
I've searched for the same problem and they said that i should edit something in *php.ini* but i cant find *php.ini* on my *cpanel*. Now I don't know what to  do :(( . Tyia.

I found these on my cpanel and i dont know what to edit. Im sorry.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find php.ini file then alternatively you can update the ini setting using below code, which can be added at the top of PHP file or your config file if you have.

```
<?php
echo ini_get('ConfigName');

if (!ini_get('ConfigName')) {
ini_set('ConfigName', 'SomeValue');
}
?>
```

**ConfigName** : will be setting name which you want to update in php.ini.
**More info**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: I updated my question and uploaded photos, that's what i only found on my cpanel

Comment: No need to update PHP.ini file. with above code you can update php.ini settings

Comment: I will add that code on my import.php? what will i write on 'SomeValue' on this part ini_set('ConfigName', 'SomeValue'); ? Thank you so much

Comment: You want to edit some values in PHP.ini, that will replace the ConfigName

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891534/launch-box-spout